# ReactiveUI.XamForms Visual Studio Project Template

Tags: xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm new to ReactiveUI and ReactiveUI.XamForms. I would like to know: is there a VS Project Template available for creating a ReactiveUI.XamForms project? (i.e. Similar to Moblie App (Xamarin.Forms) or Prism Blank App (Xamarin Forms))

Comment: that is the right place Xamarin Forms == XamForms https://reactiveui.net/api/reactiveui.xamforms/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no Visual Studio Project Template at the moment.  I know there are plans to get into the Windows Template Studio.  Nothing as of now.

Comment: Any sample apps to get a new Xaml project going with Rx?

Comment: @Shimmy ReactiveUI resolves a number of targets.  XAML can be used for several.  WPF, Xamarin.Forms, UWP.  Below is a place we are working on samples:
https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI.Samples